# Match a specific date value to a column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, join, merge, match

everyone,

I am trying to match a specific date value to another column.

For exampple,

I have two dataframes. The first data frame consists of three columns 1) individuals, 2) the locations of where the individual was observed, and 3) the date the individual was seen in that location. The second dataframe consists of 1) individuals, 2) location choices, and 3) Choice (individuals' preferred location/the location they were observed the most).

df 1:

```
    >     Indiv   Loc   Date
          1       c     8/2/200
          1       c     8/4/2020
          1       a     8/5/2020
          2       b     8/1/2020
          2       a     8/7/2020
          2       a     8/9/2020
          3       a     8/2/2020
          3       b     8/3/2020
          3       c     8/4/2020
          4       a     8/3/2020
          4       b     8/5/2020
          4       b     8/8/2020
```

df 2:

```
    >     Indiv   Loc   Choices
          1       a     No
          1       b     No
          1       c     Yes
          2       a     Yes
          2       b     No
          2       c     No
          3       a     No
          3       b     Yes
          3       c     No
          4       a     No
          4       b     Yes
          4       c     No
```

What I am trying to do is add a column to df 2 that has the date where the individual was first seen in its preferred section to each individual. Below is what I want the output to be:

Desired Output:

```
    >     Indiv   Loc   Choice   Date
          1       a     No       8/2/2020
          1       b     No       8/2/2020
          1       c     Yes      8/2/2020
          2       a     Yes      8/7/2020
          2       b     No       8/7/2020
          2       c     No       8/7/2020
          3       a     No       8/3/2020
          3       b     Yes      8/3/2020
          3       c     No       8/3/2020
          4       a     No       8/5/2020
          4       b     Yes      8/5/2020
          4       c     No       8/5/2020
```

I've tried using both the join and merge functions but haven't had much luck. Thanks stackoverflow community for your help on this.

Comment: Similar to Ben's logic you can also do : `df1 %>% right_join(df2, by = c('Indiv', 'Loc')) %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>% group_by(Indiv) %>% mutate(Date = min(Date[Choices == 'Yes'])) %>% distinct()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to do a `full_join`. Then, for each group of `Indiv`, change the `Date` to the first `Date` where `Choices` is "Yes". If your dates are not in chronological order, would add `arrange(Date)` in the pipe.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  full_join(df1, by = c("Indiv", "Loc")) %>%
  group_by(Indiv) %>%
  mutate(Date = Date[Choices == "Yes"][1]) %>%
  distinct(Indiv, Loc, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
   Indiv Loc   Choices Date    
   <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   
 1     1 a     No      8/2/2020
 2     1 b     No      8/2/2020
 3     1 c     Yes     8/2/2020
 4     2 a     Yes     8/7/2020
 5     2 b     No      8/7/2020
 6     2 c     No      8/7/2020
 7     3 a     No      8/3/2020
 8     3 b     Yes     8/3/2020
 9     3 c     No      8/3/2020
10     4 a     No      8/5/2020
11     4 b     Yes     8/5/2020
12     4 c     No      8/5/2020
```

Comment: Hi Ben. Thank you for your assistance. When I run it with the code you provided I get the message below:                                                                                                                  
 Error in UseMethod("full_join") :  
  no applicable method for 'full_join' applied to an object of class "NULL"     Why do you think that is? I tried omiting the possible blanks or NAs in both the dfs but I continue to get the same error message. Thanks

Comment: @crew4u Could you use `dput(head(df1))` and `dput(head(df2))` and put the results in your question? Just to double check your data frames?

Comment: It actually works great now :-). There was an issue with one of the classes of my variables. When I changed it, the code ran! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(data.table)

> unique(# get rid of duplicate lines as your OP suggests
       df1[df2, on = .(Indiv, Loc)  # Merge the two tables, preserving all dt2 data 
         ][ , Date_ := Date         # Temporary rename
         # Now select the minimal date for 'Yes' choices, and group by Indiv:
         ][,  Date := min(Date_[Choices == "Yes"], na.rm = TRUE), by = Indiv
         ][,  Date_ := NULL]) # clean up temporary variable

     Indiv Loc  Date      Choices
 1:     1   a 8/2/2020      No
 2:     1   b 8/2/2020      No
 3:     1   c 8/2/2020     Yes
 4:     2   a 8/7/2020     Yes
 5:     2   b 8/7/2020      No
 6:     2   c 8/7/2020      No
 7:     3   a 8/3/2020      No
 8:     3   b 8/3/2020     Yes
 9:     3   c 8/3/2020      No
10:     4   a 8/5/2020      No
11:     4   b 8/5/2020     Yes
12:     4   c 8/5/2020      No
```

Edit: the temporary variable `Date_` is not actually necessary, but I consider it cautious for debugging purposes. The one-liner solution could thus be:

```
> unique(df1[df2, on = .(Indiv, Loc)][,  Date := min(Date[Choices == "Yes"], na.rm = TRUE), by = Indiv])
```